# Interactive gantt chart component for flex

Tags: apache-flex, gantt-chart

My company have a web application product for distribution planning and scheduling. 
An important part of it is a gantt chart component where user can fine tune the schedules. Currently the gantt chart component is pure javascript+dhtml.

I am currently looking into the possibility of moving to Flex to get richer interactivity and generally nicer UI.

The question is: **is there any good interactive gantt chart component for Flex?**

By "interactive" I mean that user can interact with the gantt chart and modify data using it, as opposed to just seeing it as part of a reporting use case.
We don't mind paying if the amount worth it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ILog Elixir http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/elixir/about/?S_CMP=wspace

Strange, it wasn't owned by IBM before and it had a much better sales information when it wasn't owned by IBM.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mention that we are aware of ILOG, and we are looking for something beside their products.
My boss once worked for ILOG's competitor and still brings old sentiments. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try out the Ext Scheduler/Gantt, it's all JS/CSS and not Flex but it's still very interactive.

http://www.ext-scheduler.com/
http://www.ext-scheduler.com/gantt.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not using ExtJS currently but this is something useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the project I did for creating schedules in Flex, it has Gantt charts plus a lot of other things like money input and analysis for tasks, full undo redo support, history of all tasks, connecting tasks (FS, SS, FF) and optional lag...

Take a look at: http://www.tdteam.com/ontime/

Answer (score 1):

A Flex Gantt Chart component is available at:

http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/flex_gantt_chart_component.html

Answer (score 1):

a new one is looking really good
[gantt4flex.com](http://www.gantt4flex.com)

Answer (score 0):

Look at Tour De Flex (http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/).
You can find a lot of Free Library.
You can also find Paid Products.

Claudio.